# Error with react-router-dom and useLocation()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to `react-router-dom` and I'm trying to use the `useLocation()` hook in my app. However, I keep getting the following error: `"useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component"`.

I've tried to fix this error by wrapping my app in a `BrowserRouter`, but then I end up with another error and I feel out of my depth.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this error?

App.js File:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import NavigationMenu from "./Navigation";
import Product from "./Product";

const products = [
  {
    name: "Product 1",
    price: "£19.99",
    image: "https://osofimages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ZOOM/2018117_HR.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "Product 2",
    price: "£29.99",
    image: "https://osofimages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ZOOM/2815694_HR.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "Product 3",
    price: "£39.99",
    image:
      "https://www.hardwarestore.com/media/catalog/product/1/2/126043_1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=&width=",
  },
];

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleLogout() {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    alert("User has logged out");
    navigate("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} onLogout={handleLogout} />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavigationMenu />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <LandingPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/shop">
            <div className="products-container">
              {products.map((product, index) => (
                <Product
                  key={index}
                  name={product.name}
                  price={product.price}
                  image={product.image}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `BrowswerRouter` should be rendered higher in the ReactTree than any of the components that are trying to access the routing context it provides, e.g. the `useNavigate` and `useLocation` hooks access the context.

Remove `BrowserRouter` from `App` and ensure there is a router higher than `App` in the ReactTree.

Example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import NavigationMenu from "./Navigation";
import Product from "./Product";

...

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleLogout() {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    alert("User has logged out");
    navigate("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} onLogout={handleLogout} />
      <NavigationMenu />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/shop">
          <div className="products-container">
            {products.map((product, index) => (
              <Product
                key={index}
                name={product.name}
                price={product.price}
                image={product.image}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../App';

...

<BrowswerRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```